# how to configure iis for Zend

Tags: zend-framework, iis, web, url-rewriting

I am tryiong to configure IIS 7 to run zend without having to type /public/index.php/. If try to access my application  using this url http://<>/dev/foundation/SampleZendApp/(this is where my appliaction resides) I get the following error

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (dev)
Stack trace:

#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev\foundation\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev\foundation\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev\foundation\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dev\foundation\SampleZendApp\public\index.php(27): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'dev',
  'action' => 'foundation',
  'module' => 'default',
```

It only works  if i add the /public/index.php in front of it. How do I change in IIS so that I don't need to type /public/index.php any longer?

If any body can help me i would be very thankful.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky on iis.

Open your "Bash" :-) and execute:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config ^ -section:system.webServer/defaultDocument /+"files.[value='index.php']" ^ /commit:apphost
```

when not installed you have to add "rewrite" Module for iis:

Install: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Last step: add web.config to webroot (counterpart of .htaccess)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ZF Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello ArneRie, When i add the web.config i start to get a 500 error. I think te issue here is where my app is located. the path to my app is:http://isg-br-svcscert/dev/foundation/SampleZendApp/ and if i try to access it i get the 500 error. Anymore ideas on how i can make this work. thanks.

Comment: Do you have installed the rewrite plugin?